# How to Use MapView with WMS and WFS in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I know there are other articles about this topic, but I can't understand how to implement the `MapView` component with WMS or WFS. I have to create an app which locates me within the `MapView` with a local map in WMS and WFS format.

Comment: Please provide your code example where you have obstacle.

Comment: can you post your code ?